# find which elements of ana array add up to a sum [vba]

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

what i want to do: i have a list of data and i want to know which of the values add up to a specific sum [ie. 1.61], i would like to know all the combinations [ie. i doesn't matter how many numbers i have to add up], the anwsers should be indicated somehow

what i did: i multiplied the data, put it into three arrays and went through each element; then checked if the soulution came up before, if not the combination is indicated in a cell

```
Sub po_mojemu()
Dim macierz1(1 To 30)
Dim macierz2(1 To 30)
Dim macierz3(1 To 30)
Dim ostatnia_dane As Long
Dim ostatnia As Long

ostatnia_dane = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To ostatnia_dane
        macierz1(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
        macierz2(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
        macierz3(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

For Each element1 In macierz1
  For Each element2 In macierz2
    For Each element3 In macierz3
        If element1 + element2 + element3 = 1.61 Then
            Set c = Range("f:f").Find(What:=element1 & " : " & element2 & " : " & element3)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    ostatnia = Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Cells(ostatnia, 6) = element1 & " : " & element2 & " : " & element3
                End If
        End If
    Next element3
Next element2
Next element1

End Sub
```

what is the problem: it's not effective and it looks only at a certain case [ie. i know that there will be 30 rows of data, and i need 3 numbers that make up the sum]

i would appreciate any help that would make this code more flexible

Comment: and one other problem: it should not see the difference between elemen1&element2&element3 and elemen3&element2&element1 [and so on], but it does

Answer (score 0):

so i'll answer my own question, well not entirely but still it's better then nothing [maybe somebody will find it useful]

```
Sub ostateczna(suma As Double)
Dim macierz()
Dim ostatnia_dane As Double
Dim ostatnia As Double

ostatnia_dane = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim macierz(1 To ostatnia_dane)

For i = 1 To ostatnia_dane
    macierz(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

i = 0

For i = 1 To ostatnia_dane
For j = 1 To ostatnia_dane
    For k = 1 To ostatnia_dane
        If (i + j + k) <= ostatnia_dane Then
            If macierz(i) + macierz(i + k) + macierz(i + k + j) = suma Then
                ostatnia = Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Cells(ostatnia, 6) = macierz(i) & " : " & macierz(i + k) & " : " &  macierz(i + k + j)
            End If
        End If
    Next k
Next j
Next i
```

i think it's more efficient, and i got rid of one static value but still don't know how to counter the problem of fixed number of numbers which i want to add up.